# Measure transformer real power

Tags: transformer, current-measurement, measurement, voltage-measurement, power-measurement

I’m new at making transformers myself, and the ones that I designed had the correct output voltage, and when they were connected to batteries (previously rectified), they give me a an approximate of how much current it can deliver. My doubt is, how I can measure the real maximum current that the transformer can provide? I read some articles saying that this can be done with a bucket of salty water, and putting the outputs of the transformer with two conductors in the water. Can you explain more in detail this? Thank you!

Photos of the transformer:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Some photos of the transformer should be useful ...

Comment: Post the article that talks about this salty water scheme.

Comment: The bucket of salty water is probably used as a high power adjustable resistor.  Real resistors, incandescent light bulbs, or the element from an electric heater would be much better.

Comment: Are they made with a thermal fuse that blows before the insulation melts/burns?

Comment: @Antonio51 Done!

Comment: @MOSFET It was not an article, it was a recommendation in a comment. This one:

Comment: What you can do is prepare water with salt in a container, then take two metal sheets of 5cm x 5cm more or less connected to a piece of cable each and introduce one into the water with salt and then submerge the other a little. Little by little, watching the ammeter, if you manage to submerge it all and it still does not reach the maximum current, you bring the plate closer to the other little by little and see the current. I recommend that, if possible, do this test in AC so as not to risk burning the bridge in case the blades touch

Comment: Very importantly, at all times measuring the secondary voltage that does not fall below 20v.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes!

Comment: Usually the cross-section of steel and its type gives the power of the transformer project. Then, Volts per turn, wire cross section with regard on power,...Your transformer has a high leak inductance, because  the primary and secondary windings are separated - this is not an usual construction method. But it has a self-regulation: the voltage would drop if heavy loaded.

Comment: Almost all mains frequency transformers are thermally limited and yours should be too. Ideally, you should have a temperature senor in the middle of the winding, load the transformer for hours to heat soak it and you will have a K/W figure for it. What's the temperature rating on your magnet wire? What's the max ambient temperature you expect?

Answer (score 1):

This question is also common for power transformers.

Ideally, you can draw any power from a transformer. In practice, of course, there are limitations. You can't go forever upwards with the voltage because the core saturates and you can't go forever upwards with the current because the conductor will burn the insulation and cause a short circuit between turns and the equipment will not serve you anymore in this condition.

So, what caps the power of a transformer is the heat caused by the circulation of current, indeed.

In your equipment, you have used some kind of insulation (paper, polyester, whatever). This insulation has some temperature limit to operate under during a very long time (180.000 hours, for instance). Thus, you have to perform a heat-run test (also known as temperature rise test) to check the maximum current it can carry without exceeding the insulation temperature limit.

When performing this temperature rise test have in mind that the transformer takes some time to reach steady state.

Comment: So I will have to test with different loads, and knowing approximately the time that the transformer is ON. In this way I will know how much can it carry in the time that I need to be working, without exceeding the temperature limit. That´s okay?

Comment: Also, in the case that I rectify the output, and then connect it to a battery. Let´s say that the transformer is calculated for 48VDC and 50A. If the battery is 48VDC, and the transformer deliver 40A, wich can be the problem? I know that  this question can be literaly a new post.

Comment: When I said wich can be the problem, I mean if it simply can be solved with more turns at secondary, or more turns equally ( primary and secondary )

Comment: @samuelmattio, maybe you are missing the basics of transformer theory. The voltage ratio is defined by the turns (of course the current will happen in that ratio as well, but inverse). But the current that will flow through the windings depends on the load. The difference between having 50A or 40A in the transformer doesn't depend on the transformer, but on the load value. Maybe some circuit simulation can help you in this point.

Regarding the time your transformer will be ON, so you have a load cycle and not a continuous load. I suggest you to test for the worst condition it can face.

Answer (score 0):

> *My doubt is, how I can measure the real maximum current that the
> transformer can provide?*

You can't measure it without producing a clear test specification that dictates how long it is tested for and, under what load conditions along with measurement results that include temperature of several points within the transformer.

As designers, we work with a requirement specification that stipulates what the long-term output current should be. It seems like you have got this back to front i.e. you are winding then hoping to test. Transformers require particular attention to safety and, because of this you have to demonstrate **on paper** that your design will meet the requirements it was designed against.

> *I read some articles saying that this can be done with a bucket of
> salty water, and putting the outputs of the transformer with two
> conductors in the water. Can you explain more in detail this?*

This is a barking-mad method. Transformers are relied upon for safety against electrocution and, under no circumstances can this be proven by testing alone (and certainly not with a bucket of salty water.

Comment: So basically, you are saying that I have to trust in my calculations that are meeting the requierements of the transformer asked for?

Comment: Your calculations and load current temperature rises in several places tells you that your design is meeting expectations.